# Get domain value from maximum range value in JfreeChart

Tags: java, dataset, plot, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart 1.0.14 and I want to get the domain value from maximum range value. I use a XYLineChart and for now I get the maximum of the range value with the following code:

```
Number maximum = DatasetUtilities.findMaximumRangeValue(dataset);
maximum.floatValue();
String intensityMax = String.valueOf(maximum);
test.setText(intensityMax); //test is a jTextField
```

But how can I get the corresponding domain value from the maximum range value?

e.g. my highest value (y axis) is 8212, which corresponds to the 510 (x axis). How can I get the corresponding value of Y?

Related to this question, I have another problem. I want to put a ValueMarker to the maximum range value. For no I tried this, but I don't understand where is the problem (I don't get errors and nothing happens):

```
Number maximum = DatasetUtilities.findMaximumRangeValue(dataset);
ValueMarker max = new ValueMarker(maximum.floatValue());
max.setPaint(Color.orange);
max.setLabel("highest value");
plot.addDomainMarker(max);
```

I'm looking forward for any help,
With respect, Andrew

Comment: "get the corresponding domain value from the maximum range value" it may be the case that there are multiple domain valves corrisponding to the maximum range value

Comment: What I want is that, from the bellow code I obtain a range value (Y value), but I want to get the domain value of the corresponding Y. Practically I want X from that Y which is obtained by findMaximumRangeValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your second point, you are finding the Range maximum but adding the marker to the Domain axis.  If you modify your code thus:

```java
Number maximum = DatasetUtilities.findMaximumRangeValue(dataset);
ValueMarker max = new ValueMarker(maximum.floatValue());
max.setPaint(Color.orange);
max.setLabel("Highest Value");
max.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT);
plot.addRangeMarker(max,Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

You will get a chart like this:

[image]

On your first point, consider this chart:

[image]

There are four "higest" range valves so the domain values corrisponding to the higest value will be 2.5,4,6.g and 8.  An XYSeries has no provision for uniqure range (y) values.

You could do this

```java
    Number xValue = DatasetUtilities.findMinimumDomainValue(dataset);
    for (int seriesIndex = 0 ; seriesIndex < dataset.getSeriesCount() ; seriesIndex++){
        for (int itemIndex = 0 ; itemIndex < dataset.getItemCount(seriesIndex) ; itemIndex ++){
            Number yValue = dataset.getY(seriesIndex, itemIndex);
            if (yValue.equals(maximum)){
                if (dataset.getX(seriesIndex, itemIndex).floatValue() > xValue.floatValue())
                    xValue = dataset.getX(seriesIndex, itemIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    ValueMarker maxX = new ValueMarker(xValue.floatValue());
    maxX.setPaint(Color.red);
    maxX.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT);
    plot.addDomainMarker(maxX,Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, it works but the second point is related to the firs point; because firstly I want to get the X of my Y which is obtained by findMaximumRangeValue, and next attach a ValueMarker vertically to the domain value (x value). You get the point? or I explain in different way.

Comment: So, there is no options to extract the X value of maximum Y (using findMaximumRangeValue), and then to attach a marker to that x value (a vertical marker)?

Note: I don't use multiple series -> just one, with a single maxima.

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut I'm not aware of one

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your time! This motivate me to learn more and more...